# C++/CLI weird inheritance issue

Tags: visual-c++, inheritance, c++-cli

I have 3 classes in my project (let's name then `A`, `B` and `C`). `A` is abstract. They have the following relationship:
`A` is base class of `B`
`B` is base class of `C`

And inside `C`, I declare a variable `vector<A*> member_vector;`. This is causing the following problems:

> C3699: `'*'`: Cannot use this indirection on type `'A'`
>   C4368: cannot define `'member_vector'` as a member of managed `'C'`: mixed types are not supported.

Do you have any clues why this error is happening? I think there might be a problem with the cyclic class usage, however, how can I overcome it?

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your code, why don't you just post a representative example?  And where is the cyclic class usage?

Comment: You've definitely got something else going on here, as that's a C++/CLI error. Please post code and the details of your project.

Comment: You left out an important detail -- you're compiling with `/clr` and your 3 classes are _managed_ types.

Comment: Are you using C++/CLI? Why is there a mention of a "managed" object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to use a native type `std::vector` inside a .NET Framework managed class, in C++/CLI. If you do not know C++ *and* .NET, then C++/CLI is not advised.

Comment: I don't understand your point. I am using Visual C++. And I have already used std::vector in other programs, and it worked fine.

Comment: @jpnavarini : Visual C++ is a compiler, not a language. The _language_ you're using is C++/CLI, which is capable of using `std::vector<>`, but not in the context you're trying to use it in. You probably want to be using C++ anyway.

Comment: @ildjarn I have to create a vector of one class in the other class, is this possible in C++/CLI? Also, I think I have already done that kind of thing in other C++/CLI projects.

Comment: @jpnavarini : "vector" is much moreso a C++ concept than a C++/CLI one. Idiomatic C++/CLI code would use [`System::Collections::Generic::List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), not `std::vector<T>`. Before commenting further you **need** to grasp the difference between Visual C++, C++, and C++/CLI.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two issues happening. For one, you are using a native type in your class which is a managed class (C4368). In addition, you need to use '^' instead of '*' given that this is managed (C3699).

Comment: @jpnavarini : You're using C++/CLI, not C++ -- completely different languages. If you want to use C++, use one of the 'Win32' project templates' not one of the 'CLR' project templates.

Comment: @ildjarn had it right. Although very similar, C++/CLI is not C++ and "*" is not used in the same way.

Comment: I am aware that I am using Visual C++. I just don't know what is the difference between "*" and "^" in Visual C++.

Comment: @jpnavarini see, e.g., http://functionx.com/cppcli/index.htm and more specifically, http://functionx.com/cppcli/handles/Lesson04b.htm

Comment: @jpnavarini : Nobody pointed out that you're using Visual C++, they pointed out that you're using C++/CLI.